# Why is there no A/AN before the word pepper? I bought pepper

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, zero-article

Why is there no A/AN before the word pepper?

> I bought pepper.

Comment: I bought coffee. Pepper is uncountable. A pepper is a vegetable. Pepper is a spice. You need to provide examples and also use a dictionary before asking. Thanks.

Comment: I meant pepper which is a vegetable.
For example, I bought pepper and a bottle at the store.
Why is there no A before the pepper?

Comment: @שבילוי If you mean the vegetable, you need "a/an", and "I bought pepper" is a mistake. Where did you see this sentence?

Answer (score 4):

We use the indefinite article "a/an" before *countable nouns* only.

The word "pepper" can be either countable or uncountable.

If it's countable, it means the individual fruit of a *capsicum* plant, like these four:

[image: four devil's tongue red peppers]

If "pepper" is uncountable, then it means peppercorns, which are the fruit of the black pepper plant, either whole or in ground form, like these:

[image: shallow dish of mixed peppercorns] [image: pepper shaker with ground black pepper]

So "a pepper" means the first type, and without "a/an" means it's the second type. So in your example sentence, we know they bought black peppercorns or ground black pepper.

Answer (score 2):

In general, "a" implies a quantity of 1.

If you buy one whole pepper (️), you have bought **a pepper**.

But "pepper" can also be a mass noun, when referring to ground pepper (as a spice). You might measure it in grams. Here the indefinite article is not used:

> I bought pepper.
>
> I bought some pepper.
>
> I bought 1 gram of pepper.

Comment: Pepper as a mass noun can also refer to an indefinite quantity of unground peppercorns (as a spice).  Grinding is not a necessary condition for the use of the uncountable sense.